# Does linux c/c++ programming support setting process priority?

Tags: c++, linux, process, posix

Under linux, I can use "nice" command to set process priority, NP. But I didn't find a way to set this information within my c program, I don't find clue in [APUE] book.

Is there a posix api to do this job?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/nice.htm

Comment: How about the [`nice`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nice.2.html) system call?

Comment: Or, for finer-grained control, `pthread_setschedparam()` and `pthread_setschedprio()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nice() function in unistd.h.

Example :

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    nice(4); // To set level 4 as nice value to current process
    return 0;
}
```